# Working on iOS 8 platform

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an app for iOS  8 platform and need to make full screen graphics for iOS 4 , 5 and 6. With each having multiple sizes. My problem is how to name the graphical images especially full screen for instance tutorial screens for all three, how do I differentiate between 5 and 6 especially when they are using same image. I am getting images from a designer and the ios model 4 5 and 6 i am referring to are ios hardware model on which the application will be launched..What I want to know is do I put the model name in the image name like:

image_tutorial_iphone4_1@2x for iphone4
image_tutorial_iphone5_1@2x for iphone5
image_tutorial_1@3x for iphone6

Comment: Are you creating your interface programatically ?

Comment: With "iOS 4, 5 and 6" do you mean "iPhone 4, 5 and 6"? (the hardware models, not the software versions) Otherwise, I don't understand the question.